# Number of ways of partitioning an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

> Given an array of `n` elements, a k-partitioning of the array would be to split the array in `k` contiguous subarrays such that the maximums of the subarrays are non-increasing. Namely `max(subarray1) >= max(subarray2) >= ... >= max(subarrayK)`.
>
> In how **many ways** can an array be partitioned into valid partitions like the ones mentioned before?
>
> **Note**: `k` isn't given as input or anything, I mereley used it to illustrate the general case. A partition could have any size from `1` to `n`, we just need to find all the valid ones.

Example, the array [3, 2, 1] can be partitioned in 4 ways, you can see them below:

The valid partitions :[3, 2, 1]; [3, [2, 1]]; [[3, 2], 1]; [[3], [2], [1]].

I've found a similar problem related to linear partitioning, but I couldn't find a way to adapt the thinking to this problem. I'm pretty sure this is dynamic programming, but I haven't been able to properly identify
how to model the problem using a recurrence relation.
How would you solve this?

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm to do this, or are you looking for a way to do this in a programing language? If the first, your question is off-topic for SO, for the latter, please add the programing language you are using and the attempts you made to solve your problem

Comment: The first, please revisit the rules to remind yourself of the scope of this site. I can show you at least 10 related questions on SO that require the same way of thinking as my problem does and nobody shut them down.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm quite aware of the rules. Your question isn't about a programing problem, though off-topic (That you found other off-topic questions doesn't make yours better)

Comment: Algorithmic questions are perfectly fine.

Comment: No, you're not. I'm sick and tired of this passive aggressive attitude displayed by some members of this community. Each time I post an algorithmic question that people can't solve right away or throw some mindless reference to a random page, frustration gets the better of them and try to close the question. There are COUNTLESS questions like this one here and they are all within the scope of this site. Please don't comment on this section anymore if you're not going to be constructive. Good day

Comment: @user2357112 no https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-software-engin

Comment: @baao I will just consider a high-level algorithm description a subset or extension of pseudocode (or that this question is asking for pseudocode) and refer you to ["Algorithms expressed in pseudocode straddle the border"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in). It's definitely on topic on CS, but it will take some convincing for me to believe it's not **also** on topic for SO (and then it will take a whole lot of convincing on top of that for everyone else to actually close questions here or ask on CS).

Comment: @baao Algorithm questions here tend to draw a lot more practical answers (often containing actual code), while questions on CS tend to draw more theoretical answers (rarely / never containing actual code, often not even pseudo-code), and CS answers also tends to assume people have a lot of pre-existing knowledge, while SO answers are less so. Seems fairly distinct and any given asker might prefer one or the other, so they'd pick the appropriate site. Seems fine.

Comment: OP clearly stated he's looking for an algorithm, not looking for code solving the same. He's not even asking for pseudocode and clearly stated he's not after a programing based solution. The question is solely off-topic for SO. The only reason why someone who knows about CS would ask this kind of question here is because they know that there are 10 times more people on SO than on CS, so they ask here in good hope that someone sees the question and answers earlier. @Dukeling

Comment: @Dukeling and I'm not the one who should convince you, just read the meta posts (there are plenty of them on different sites) about the exact same problem. The answer is clear, a question like the one asked is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call an element of the input a *tail-max* if it is at least as great as all elements that follow. For example, in the following input:

```
5 9 3 3 1 2
```

the following elements are tail-maxes:

```
5 9 3 3 1 2
  ^ ^ ^   ^
```

In a valid partition, every subarray must contain the next tail-max at or after the subarray's starting position; otherwise, the next tail-max will be the max of some later subarray, and the condition of non-increasing subarray maximums will be violated.

On the other hand, if every subarray contains the next tail-max at or after the subarray's starting position, then the partition must be valid, as the definition of a tail-max ensures that the maximum of a later subarray cannot be greater.

If we identify the tail-maxes of an array, for example

```
1 1 9 2 1 6 5 1
. . X . . X X X
```

where X means tail-max and . means not, then we can't place any subarray boundaries before the first tail-max, because if we do, the first subarray won't contain a tail-max. We can place at most one subarray boundary between a tail-max and the next; if we place more, we get a subarray that doesn't contain a tail-max. The last tail-max must be the last element of the input, so we can't place a subarray boundary after the last tail-max.

If there are `m` non-tail-max elements between a tail-max and the next, that gives us `m+2` options: `m+1` places to put an array boundary, or we can choose not to place a boundary between these elements. These factors are multiplicative.

We can make one pass from the end of the input to the start, identifying the lengths of the gaps between tail-maxes and multiplying together the appropriate factors to solve the problem in `O(n)` time:

```
def partitions(array):
    tailmax = None
    factor = 1
    result = 1
    for i in reversed(array):
        if tailmax is None:
            tailmax = i
            continue
        factor += 1
        if i >= tailmax:
            # i is a new tail-max.
            # Multiply the result by a factor indicating how many options we
            # have for placing a boundary between i and the old tail-max.
            tailmax = i
            result *= factor
            factor = 1
    return result
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you for the idea and the detailed explanation !

Answer (score -1):

**Update:** Sorry I misunderstanding the problem. In this case, split the arrays to sub-arrays where every tails is the max element in the array, then it will work in narrow cases. e.g. [2 4 5 9 6 8 3 1] would be split to [[2 4 5 9] 6 8 9 3 1] first. Then we can freely chose range 0 - 5 to decide whether following are included. You can use an array to record the result of DP. Our goal is `res[0]`. We already have `res[0] = res[5] + res[6] + res[7] + res[8] + res[9] + res[10]` in above example and res[10] = 1

```
def getnum(array):
    res = [-1 for x in range(len(array))]
    res[0] = valueAt(array, res, 0)
    return res[0]

def valueAt(array, res, i):
    m = array[i]
    idx = i
    for index in range(i, len(array), 1):
        if array[index] > m:
            idx = index
            m = array[index]
    value = 1;
    for index in range(idx + 1, len(array), 1):
        if res[index] == -1:
            res[index] = valueAt(array, res, index)
        value = value + res[index]
    return value;
```

Worse than the answer above in time consuming. DP always costs a lot.

**Old Answer:** If **no duplicate elements** in an array is allowed, the following way would work:

Notice that the number of sub-arrays is not depends on the values of elements if no duplicate. We can remark the number is `N(n)` if there is n elements in array.

The largest element must be in the first sub-arrays, other elements can be in or not in the first sub-array. Depends on whether they are in the first sub-array, the number of partitions for the remaining elements varies.

So,
`N(n) = C(n-1, 1)N(n-1) + C(n-1, 2)N(n-2) + ... + C(n-1, n-1)N(0)`

where C(n,k) means:

[image]

Then it can be solved by DP.

Hope this helps

Comment: "Notice that the number of sub-arrays is not depends on the values of elements if no duplicate." - what do you mean? `[1, 2, 3]` has only one valid partition, while `[3, 2, 1]` has four. Your answer doesn't work.

Comment: Did you miss the contiguity constraint?